Upgrade to 24.04.1 caused problems with nightly "updates"
I upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04.1 this monday. The upgrade was smooth and everything seemed fine. However, afterwards there is a restart and system "update" each night, with exactly the same content: update of google-chrome-stable and microsoft-edge-stable and downgrade (!) of ubuntu-advantage-tools and ubuntu-pro-client (24.04.1 version -> 24.04). This "update" also drains the laptop battery completely.

There is also mention of a firmware (?) update

Any ideas how to resolve this?
Update: this seems to happen every reboot. So I guess the nightly occurence is due to the battery being drained.

When the power is drained, the upgrades cannot complete. So they try again. Either reschedule the upgrade for a time when your device is on mains power, or just leave the device plugged in to mains power overnight.

I have tried restarting on main power, but get the same update message every time. I have not had it plugged in over night though, will try and see if that helps.Why suspend doesn't work as it used to is another issue.
